# Image Alignment in Div centered with Jquery

Tags: javascript, css, image, alignment, center

SO, 
I've got a horizontally and vertically centered div for a landing page. I'm attempting to add an image to the div, but as soon as I insert it, the content of the centered div is either pushed to the bottom of the screen or to one side (see the page [here](http://adrienneadams.org/landing/)). I've tried to solve the problem with this CSS:

```
#landlogo {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: left;
clear: both;
}
```

But to no avail. For some reason, the image refuses to align to the center just above the text like the other components on the page. I suppose there could be an issue with the Jquery that somehow prevents it from properly centering with images, but I thought perhaps I'd run it by the much sharper minds on SO before I try any more in-depth solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `float:left` being applied to the img.

As soon as I remove that css in my browser, it centers itself.

Comment: Douglas, I updated the CSS and sure enough! However, the image was still pushing the centered div too far; to solve this I applied a -100px top margin to the image, and that seems to have done the trick. Thanks so much!